# Excel - Script that search a sheet for a cell containing specific text, and replace the text with a specific value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I want to split a cell with data into other cells based on the data in the original cell. The data from the original cell looks like this (all content in a single cell):

```
Field95-4,Field97-4,Field98-0,Field100-2,Field103-0,Field105-3,Field107-4,Field109-4,Field110-2,Field111-0,Field112-0,Field113-192,Field114-87,Field115-0,Field116-0,Field117-60
```

It should be split using "," as a delimiter. I found out that I could do that with a script:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim X As Variant
X = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
Range("A1").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
End Sub
```

Then the result is like this:

```
Field95-4
Field97-4
Field98-0
Field100-2
Field103-0
Field105-3
Field107-4
Field109-4
Field110-2
Field111-0
Field112-0
Field113-192
Field114-87
Field115-0
Field116-0
Field117-60
```

Each value is a single token that contains two parts divided by a hyphen; the original cell content and its replacement value.
The script should look for a cell containing the first part of the token, the 'fieldnumber' part.

For Example, There is a cell containing the text 'Field95', and a cell with the text 'Field97' etc. Then I want to replace the first part of the token with the second part. So for 'Field95-4', a cell with the content 'Field95' should be found and replaced by the text '4'. The cell with the content 'Field97' should be replaced with '4'. etc.

This is an excel file I uploaded, so you can see what my question is about. It contains the data.
[link](http://www.misb.dk/questionWithData.xlsx)

I know it's much to ask, but we tried a lot, and I can't get it to work.

I'm looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it case-sensitive?

Comment: @Raystafarian no :) Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your values are in one range and your search & replace range **does not include that range**, something like this might work (adjust the ranges, try out on a copy of your data)-

```
Sub test()
Dim X As Variant
X = Split(Range("A2").Value, ",")
Range("A2").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
End Sub

Sub test2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strReplace As String
Dim strSearch As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'Loop through cells
For Each c In Range("A2:A17")
    'Select non-blanks
    If c.Value <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
        'Get length of cell
        j = Len(c)
        'Find first delimiter and store position
        i = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("-", c.Value)
        'Get strings!
        strSearch = Left(c, i - 1)
        strReplace = Right(c, j - i)
        'Find and Replace
        Range("c2:c121").Cells.Replace What:=strSearch, Replacement:=strReplace, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    End If
 Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I just tried it out, and I think I am doing something wrong here. Nothing is happening ;) What do you mean Assuming my values are in one range? I know its a lot to ask, but do you mind downloading the file i linked to, and actually creating the macro? I would be SOOOO glad. Played around with this issue for more than 10 hours now hehe

Comment: in the `for each c in range(` line it says "A:A" which is the range you need to change that your values are in. In the `range("B:B").cells.replace` line, the "B:B" needs to be changed to your range that you're searching.

Comment: We are almost there. It actually replaces some of the fields with data. The problem is, that is not the correct fields that is being updated. They does not match the B:B data (field95-4). I have column A with rows containing the data from field1 to field 120, then I have column B with the data that should be replaced into the correct A:A field. (e-g. field95-4). What could that be ?

Comment: see new answer, it works for the sheet you uploaded.

Comment: I actually found an error in the  script. I don't how to fix it, but I created an excel file that contain the script and that produces the error. When the script "replaceRowData" has finished, the Fields are filled with numbers from 1-34 etc. I think there is some kind of loop problem? Here is the link to the new file: [link](http://www.misb.dk/questionWithData2.xlsm) We are reeeaaaly close now  hehe

Comment: Ray do you get the same error or is it me who are using the script in a wrong way? :D

Comment: No, the issue is that Fields 10-19 include the string "Field1" so they are being replaced. Same goes for 20-29, 30-39, etc. Modify the search string to fit your data, I suppose. Change `xlPart` to `xlWhole`